# Simulating given probability density function in R

Tags: r, probability

The following p.d.f is given:

```
f(x)=2x/k^2, where 0 <= x <= k
```

Let k=10, I'm trying to simulate 100 times for this p.d.f, then print the first 5 results and find the mean for all 100 times results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simulate with a uniform distribution between `0` and `k`, then you can pass `runif(n, min, max)` into your pdf.

```
f <- function(x, k) {
  return(2*x/k^2)
}

k <- 10
res <- f(runif(100, 0, k), k)
print(res[1:5])
print(mean(res))
```

Per MrFlick's comments, if you were instead wanting to do inverse transform sampling, this should suffice.

```
pdf <- function(x, k) {
  return(2*x/k^2)
}

cdf <- function(x, k){
  return(x^2/k^2)
}

icdf <- function(y, k){
  return(sqrt(k^2*y))
}

k <- 10
res <- icdf(runif(100,0,1), k)
print(res[1:5])
print(mean(res))
```

Comment: This seems very wrong. If `k=100`, then this distribution should return numbers from 0 to 100. But if you pass in 0-1 for `x` into `f`, you'll never get a number larger than `2/100^2`. I think you were trying to get at [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) but that involves finding the *inverse* of the *cdf*, not plugging random 0-1 values into the pdf.

Comment: My understanding (if I am reading the question correctly) is that if `k=100`, then if you integrate `f(x)` over `0` to `k=100` you will get `1` (as with any `k` to be a valid pdf).  Thus, the distribution should take in a random sample from 0-100 to map to a range of 0-1.

Comment: But your code doesn't take that integration into account at all. That's a very important step. And that's why the CDF should be used with inverse transform sampling.

Comment: This particular integral isn't hard to solve by hand. For `k=100`, the expected value (mean) is 66.6. This code gives a much, much smaller value than expected.

Comment: This seems to be a case of having different interpretations of the question without any context provided.  I understood it to mean simply generating a uniform sample from 0-k and feeding it into the pdf to give probabilities as outputs, while another interpretation would be generating a uniform sample from 0-1 and using the cdf to return a number from 0-k from the underlying distribution given (as you mention).  After re-reading, it is probably more likely the user was asking for the later.  I appreciate the feedback.